# Excel Sumifs Dynamic Sum Ranges and Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I keep track of my personal budget by using Google Forms. Every time I spend money on something, I will submit a form that tracks what the expense was and how much it was. For example an entry could look like Gas -$24.00 or Groceries -$75.00. What I like about this is, when I get paid, I look at all my entries over the last pay period and I am able to adjust my budget accordingly.

Long story short, I have these form entries, which are all time-stamped, sync to an excel document on my computer. What I am trying to do is sum each 'category' (ie Gas, Groceries, etc) based on a range of dates.

For example, my form responses spreadsheet would look something like this:

```
     A          B            C
1    Timestamp  Envelope     Amount
2    5/26/2017  Groceries    $(50.00)
3    5/27/2017  Gas          $(30.00)
4    5/28/2017  Utilities    $(200.00)
5    6/5/2017   Gas          $(25.00)
6    6/5/2017   Pets         $(40.00)
7    6/6/2017   Groceries    $(75.00)
8    6/6/2017   Auto         $(40.00)
```

Lets say I want to sum all the entries for 'Gas' in the last 10 days. So between 5/27/2017 and 6/6/2017, I want excel to automatically tell me I spent $55. Also, if I add a new entry tomorrow for -$20, Excel will automatically recalculate to include the new entry, but also exclude the entry on the 27th, since it's too old.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So something like `=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,">"&TODAY()-10,B:B,"Groceries")`?  (Or maybe ">=" - depends on whether you mean the 11 days from 5/27 to 6/6, which would need ">=", or the 10 days from 5/28 to 6/6, which would need ">")

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=SUMIFS(D4:D10,C4:C10,"Gas",$B$4:$B$10,">="&DATE(2017,5,27),B4:B10,"<="&TODAY())
```

[image]

Let me know if that works for you.